# Which guitar to buy considering the scenario?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, semi-acoustic-guitar

I have been playing guitar for almost 4 years now, and have only played the guitar which I have, haven't got to have chance on multiple guitar, so don't have experience on different models. I have a local guitar, and now thinking to buy a branded electo- acoustic guitar or semi-acoustic guitar (fender or cort preferably).

I am confused which model I should go for.

The point here is I asked someone that which guitar and I came to know about models like Fender Sa105ce, fender Fa125ce. But when I went to the shop to see these guitars that how they sound.. i felt that they sound very thin,sharp and bassless. The local guitar which I have, I felt that is way better than these. If anyone of you who is/are experienced in trying different models of guitar(or even they have tried these models and bassy models also), then he/she might be understanding what I am trying to say. I feel my local guitar has more balanced kind of sound, soft and bassy sound with a good sprinkle of treble in it. I also tried Cort Ce304t and I can say it's sound it almost same as what my local guitar sounds like. But it was getting out of my budget. I am not sure how good Cort Ce304t, but as it sounded like my local guitar, and till now as I have played only my local guitar and haven't tried different models, that's why it sounded good to my ears probably.

I hope I am clear to you and able to make you understand my point.

Now the thing is my budget is INR 10k-12k or even I can increase it to INR 14-15k also. Or even INR 16k also but not a single penny more than that I would be able to pay for guitar, as that would go out of my budget.

I also play heartbeat style, so it becomes a bit necessary that the body should be rigid and hard and not fragile as I can break fragile body guitar easily due to heartbeat style.

If anyone can suggest me a good guitar while keeping my point in consideration, also which are available in India,  would be very helpful as I have already started to loose the tightness on my finger tips and feeling sad and but worried about it.

Also I am open to good models of good brands other than what models I have mentioned.

Comment: We can't tell you which guitar to buy, only your hands, ears & wallet can decide that. Notes: 1) changing strings from the twangy nasties they put on cheap guitars when new can help, but you'll not know how much until after you've bought it. 2) When quoting prices at 10-15k or so, we're going to have to assume that's not dollars or pounds… but unless you tell us, we have no clue what value you actually mean.

Comment: Right. That's what I felt that my hands and ears can only decide it. But if I ask someone, then what should I say to them that what kind of guitar is that which has proper balanced bass and treble and not just treble only? Is these kinds of guitar have some special type (like my local one)?  And yes  I have updated the question. The amount is in INR actually.

Comment: 100inr=£1 roughly. So £100 isn't going to buy anything spectacular. Think pre-loved...  Not a clue what 'heartbeat style' is.

Comment: If you feel like these guitars sound overly thin and lack body this _might_ come from pickups being too low.

Comment: If the guitar you already have is good, why not just add an aftermarket piezo bridge insert to it?